# How to push data in empty space in array using foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this below code where in I am trying to push 'No Data' in one of the index in array which doesn't have data.

```
data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

onClick() {
    this.data.forEach(element => {
      if (element == '') {
        element.push('No Data');
      }
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

But I am getting error as TypeError: element.push is not a function.

What is wrong in the code and is there any better ways to solve this?

Comment: `element` is not an array. `push` function is only supported for array.

Comment: element is a string. You know this, because you're checking if it's the one that's empty. So why do you think it has a push method?

Comment: a string is no array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of your array is a string.

Strings don't have a push method and they cannot because they are immutable. That is you can't change the characters in a string.

This is trivially solved however, as follows:

```
this.data = this.data.map(d => d === '' ? 'No Data' : d);
```

What we've done here, is use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array into a new array with all of the empty string elements replaced as per your specifications.

In context:

```
data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

onClick() {
  this.data = this.data.map(d => d === '' ? 'No Data' : d);
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let list = this.data.map(d => d === '' ? 'No data' : d)
```

Answer (score 1):

element is the string you can't push, use array.map to solve this

```
const data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

onClick() {
   const list = this.data.map(element => {
      if (element === '') {
        return 'No Data';
      }
      return element;
    });
    console.log(list);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the array with replacements.

```js
let data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

data = data.map(v => v || 'No Data');

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

var dataArray = new Array();

    data.forEach(element => {
      if (element == '') {
        dataArray.push('No Data');
      }
      else
      {
       dataArray.push(element);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.dataArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `element` is a string while `push` function is only supported for array. Just return `'No data'` in case `element` is empty string:

```js
data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];

onClick() {
    this.data = this.data.map(v => v || 'No Data');
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use for or for each loop so that particular element is a string, not an array that why its shows ***element.push is not a function.***

to change element of an array you can use this method

```
 data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', 'e'];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if (data[i] == '')
            data[i] = 'No Data';}
    console.log(data)
```